# Linking WiFi MCU to Ethernet PHY via PCIe

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, wifi, pcie, phy

I'm trying to link [this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Microchip-Technology-Atmel/EVB-LAN7430?qs=3HJ2avRr9PK9nxXiYMRJaw%3D%3D) Ethernet PHY to [this](https://www.nxp.com/products/wireless/wi-fi-plus-bluetooth/aw-xm458ma-evaluation-board:AW-XM458MA) WiFi 6 MCU via PCIe to make a single port router.

Can I directly connect these two, or do I need some kind of host CPU with two PCIe slots to link them?

The WiFi module already has its own MCU, so ideally I'd like to bridge these two without adding another MCU/CPU.

Comment: As you’ve figured, you would need another cpu with a pcie root complex. In your other post it was suggested you use a WiFi router chip. Buy yourself a WiFi router with your required specs and pull it apart. See what devices are used. That is your solution.

Comment: Does it really have to be *that* PHY and *that* MCU?

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help!

Comment: No doesn’t have to be. Just WiFi 6 with up to 1 Gbit Ethernet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know... You'll need a CPU with drivers. There isn't anything in the documentation that says the wifi 6 module supports an RGMII/MII interface, which is what you need to go direct.

To go direct between Ethernet Phys\controllers you need RGMII/MII which can translate the packets to an interface between chip to chip. The wifi has no such interface.

You would also need some kind of operating system to setup the registers on the wifi to switch channels and configure AP's and other things.

Comment: Thank you this is super helpful! I’m surprised single WiFi-Ethernet bridge ICs aren’t more common. Most of the options I’ve seen for this type of conversion require at least 3 chips

Comment: They’re not common as there is little demand for them. Even the small wireless routers use chips that can support a number of wired ports even if they only actually use one of them. That’s been the case for many years, so there must be a message in there. You might want to look up MT7621A.